# How to give the dtpicker date – 1?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, datepicker

Now using VS 2008

Before I used VB 6, now I Upgraded to VB 2008.

VB6 Code

```
sdate = DateToString(dtpicker1 - 1)
edate = DateToString(dtpicker2)
```

Above code is working fine.

After Upgraded to VB 2008

```
sdate = DateToString(dtpicker1._Value)
edate = DateToString(dtpicker2._Value)
```

If I Put

```
sdate = DateToString(dtpicker1._Value - 1)
```

It is showing Error.

How can I write a code like dtpicker1 – 1

Need VB code Help.

Comment: I DateToString a function you have defined yourself? Then you might want to change the contents of that to use improved .NET date functions. `Date.ToShortDateString()` returns it in the format specified by the short date format in regional settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Value is of type `Object`.
That is because the value of a datepicker can be either a valid date, or empty. So you need:

```
If IsDate(dtpicker1._Value) Then
  sdate = CDate(dtpicker1._Value).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()
End If
```

If the value is empty, it actually has a type of `System.DBNull` , which means that for conversion to string, you can define two functions with identical names, but different parameter types:

```
Public Function DateToString(ByVal _date As Date) As String
    Return _date.ToShortDateString()
End Function  

Public Function DateToString(ByVal _date As DBNull) As String
    Return "No date selected!"
End Function
```

You can then modify your previous code to this:

```
Dim theDate As Object
theDate = dtpicker1._Value
If IsDate(theDate) Then
  theDate = CDate(theDate).AddDays(-1)
End If
sdate = DateToString(theDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to subtract one day from dtpicker1's value? If so, do this:

```
sdate = DateToString(dtpicker1._Value.AddDays(-1))
```

Comment: When I press dtpicker1.value.(After . Press nothing display) when i enter .addday(-1).tostring. It displaying error

Answer (score 0):

Bit unsure of what you are trying to do, but for the following solution I'm assuming that by -1 you are saying that you want to get the day before the date.
If so then use

```
dtpicker1._Value.AddDays(-1).ToString
```

On top of that if you want to format the string that comes out, you can do that by using a format string such as

```
dtpicker1._Value.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

which will print the date out like "20/08/2009".

Comment: When I press dtpicker1.value.(After . Press nothing display) when i enter .addday(-1).tostring. It displaying error